# Simple ehcache program to verify network settings for multicast

Tags: linux, ehcache, aix, multicast, distributed-caching

I'm looking for a simple ehcache program example to verify network settings for multicast. There are many postings about issues with configuring multicast for ehcache. I'd like a simple script/program that can start two java vms and verify that cache updates are communicated between the VMs, thus verifying that multicast configuration works on the single server, and an extension of the program that can work on multiple servers, verifying that ehcache is working between the servers.

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JGroups have tools for checking IP multicast, see [the manual on chapter 2](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/ch02.html#ItDoesntWork). The `McastReceiverTest` and `McastSenderTest` are easy to use:

start receiver on one machine

```
java org.jgroups.tests.McastReceiverTest -mcast_addr 224.10.10.10 -port 5555
```

and sender on another

```
java org.jgroups.tests.McastSenderTest -mcast_addr 224.10.10.10 -port 5555
```

(maybe add `-jar jgroups-X.jar`)

The sender transmits messages from the shell to all receivers, e.g.:

sender:

```
Socket=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:55276, ttl=32, bind interface=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
> foo
> << Received response from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5555: Hello from Bela
```

receiver:

```
Socket=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5555, bind interface=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
foo [sender=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:55276]
```

Comment: I found the ehcache debugger 1.7.1 can be helpful. I also wrote a very simple multi-cast example program. Ideally, I'd like a very simple ehcache program to run twice on the machine or on two separate machines and demonstrate a working network configuration for ehache.